# Indexing a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am new to Python and I am trying to use indexing to obtain the last name along each row.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def manager(vec):
    for i,val in enumerate(vec):
        if val == np.NaN:
            break

        return vec[i - 1]

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[23,15,20], 'L1_name': ['Andrew','Thomas','Thomas'],
                'L1_ID': [234,994,994],'L2_Name':['Andrew','Alice','Thomas'],'L2_ID':[234,237,994],
                'L3_Name':['Jerico','Sarah',np.nan],'L3_ID':[453,237,np.nan]})

    df['new'] = df.apply(manager, axis=1)
df
```

What am i doing wrongly, anyone?

Comment: your code ist probably not correctly formated. Your function `manager` returns in the first round of the foor loop, either with `vec[- 1]` or `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with forward filling per rows of missing values with seelct last column by positions:

```
s = df.filter(like='Name').ffill(axis=1).iloc[:,-1]
print (s)
0    Jerico
1     Sarah
2    Thomas
Name: L3_Name, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this works

```py
def manager(vec):
    return vec.dropna().iloc[-2]
```